# DC/OS stuck at service deployment

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, dcos

Have build a test DC/OS cluster with 3 masters and 2 **public** agents. Everything looks good. Even deployed application through Marathon with `"acceptedResourceRoles":["slave_public"]` configuration. However, when I want to deploy the Spark service through the Catalog section, it stucks for a long time and says `DCOS has been waiting for resources for xx minutes.`.

My question is, does the services in the repo can only be deployed in the private agents?

If not the case, how can I deploy them in the publish agents?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catalog deploys services on *private* agents. Public agents are intended only to run load balancers and other tools to control access to services on private agents :) Might want to make some private ones.

For more info on agent types see [these docs](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.10/overview/architecture/node-types/)

If you do want your cluster to run workloads on public agents, I think there is some extra configuration you need to set, but I'm not finding it at the moment. It's a bit of an antipattern though.